# Initialization list on different subclasses

Tags: c#

I've got a large, abstract, class `InfoBase` with lots of properties. Then there are a few subclasses, which have a handful of properties. I will recieve an object with information to instansiate a subclass object of `InfoBase` which will then be returned, something like this:

```
private static InfoBase CreateInfo(Dictionary<string, string> userInput) {
    InfoBase info;
    if(userInput["InfoType"] == "SomeInfo") {
        info = new SomeInfo {
            sharedData1 = Process(userInput["data1"]),
            sharedData2 = ProcessDifferently(userInput["data2"] + userInput["AuxData"]),
            // ...
            specialData1 = Something(userInput["blah"])
        };
    }
    else if(userInput["InfoType"] == "OtherInfo") {
    // ... And so on
    }
    return info;
}
```

Almost all the fields of the `info` object will be initialized in the same way, so I'd like to share that initialization instead of copy/pasting it, and just change the specifics. I'd like to do the shared initialization with an initialization list, instead of having twenty rows of `info.data1 = ...;`. Is this possible? Ideally, something like this:

```
InfoBase info = WhateverMagicStuff { 
    sharedData1 = // ...
};
SomeInfo specificInfo = SomeInfo(info);
specificInfo.specialData1 = // ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the shared data after the if else block.

```
private static InfoBase CreateInfo(Dictionary<string, string> userInput) {
    InfoBase info;
    if(userInput["InfoType"] == "SomeInfo") {
        info = new SomeInfo {
            // ...
            specialData1 = Something(userInput["blah"])
        };
    }
    else if(userInput["InfoType"] == "OtherInfo") {
    // ... And so on
    }
    else { ... }

    info.sharedData1 = Process(userInput["data1"]),
    info.sharedData2 = ProcessDifferently(userInput["data2"] + userInput["AuxData"]),

    return info;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void PopulateInfoBase(InfoBase infoToPopulate, WhateverUserInputIs userInput)
{
    infoToPopulate.sharedData1 = Process(userInput["data1"]);
    infoToPopulate.sharedData2 = ProcessDifferently(userInput["data2"] + userInput["AuxData"]);
    etc etc
}
```

Call the above function after instantiating the specific subclass you need (and populating its 'special' data).